# How to properly implement unit test with Angular route parameters?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  // selector: 'app-view1',
  template: '<h1>{{ title$ | async }}</h1>',
  // templateUrl: './view1.component.html',
  // styleUrls: ['./view1.component.css']
})
export class View1Component implements OnInit {
  public title$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('view1 init');
    this.title$ = this._route.params.pipe(
      map((value: Params) => {
        console.log(value);
        return value['title'] || 'no title';
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I have a simple view component like above. The component will be loaded into my may component using `<router-outlet>.` The *Routes* configuration in the module file looks like below.

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'view1', component: View1Component },
  { path: 'view1/:title', component: View1Component }
];
```

I am struggling to implement unit tests for this component. More specifically, I have no idea how to correctly inject the  `ActivatedRoute` value into the component, and how to handle the async-scenarios.

Comment: So you want to unit test `ViewComponent1` or `appRoutes`? They are two separate tests. You can test `ViewComponent1` independently without involving routes

Comment: @AmitChigadani, I want to test `ViewComponent1`. I think I need to inject an `ActivatedRoute` into its constructor, which can provide the *title* value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mock `ActivatedRoute` in your test spec file, since this a component testing, you wont get `activated route` details before loading the component.

You can start your test component this way :

```
let activatedRoute = jasmine.createSpyObj<ActivatedRoute>("ActivatedRoute", ['params']); // create mock object   
activatedRoute.params = Observable.of({id:'123'});   // set mock params or any other stuff

beforeEach(() => {    
    //Configuring testing environment
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule],
        providers: [MyProvider,
              // override ActivateRoute injector with mock object
            {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute}
        ],

    });
});
```

There are many tutorials which explain to test asynchronous methods in angular.

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/

https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync